# Event Receiver ListUrl, to a list name with a Space in the URL

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

Event Receiver not firing when the list have a space within the name:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
          <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Style Library">
            <Receiver>
              <Name>EventReceiverItemAdded</Name>
              <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
              <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
              <Class>Corporate.MEEventReceiver.TRSEventReceiver</Class>
              <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
            </Receiver>
      </Receivers>
    </Elements>
```

i tried `<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Style%20Library">` and `<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Style&#032;Library">` , but still not working.

Comment: just use name as it is library, for lists u have to mention Lists/ListTitle

Answer (score 1):

You use **"Style Library"** as **Display Name**. It has white space in between.So by default SharePoint changes it to "**Share%20Library**" as **External Name**.  We can use them with there **Internal Names** . For Internal Name SharePoint Converts there special character into Inernal Hex code.
For white space you can use ***x0020*** in Internal Name.
You can use below link for reference.

[Internal Names mapping for all characters](https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/sharepoint-column-names-internal-name-mappings-for-non-alphabet/)

```
Style_x0020_Library
```

Comment: I tried it but it (Style_x0020_Library) is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListUrl="Style Library"` or `ListUrl="Style%20Library"`.

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Style Library">
            <Receiver>
              <Name>EventReceiverItemAdded</Name>
              <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
              <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
              <Class>Corporate.MEEventReceiver.TRSEventReceiver</Class>
              <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
            </Receiver>
</Receivers>
```